# Jquery Datatables, pagination and mvc. Take x amount from database

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc, linq, datatables

Having abit of an issue with `datatables`, I want all the data from my sql table, however running it on our site is causing some severe lag as it has over 8000 records. So I tried using `Take(10).ToList();` in my controller, however jquery datatables will only populate with 10 records (obviously). I am hoping there is a simple method or approach in my controller that I could take, for only loading ten records at a time. Yet still keeping the pagination of the entire sql table in the datatables. (Long shot)

For instance if I load the entire table data into the datatable it has something like 800+ paged pages. If I only take 10 records at a time datatables will only show one page. I need to take 10 records at a time but also show 800 paged pages and when I click next or on a specific paged page it will load those records. Can this be done from the controller/linq? Without taking an exhaustively long trip down json/ajax lane.

**Controller**

```
    public PartialViewResult Listing()
    {
        var model = _db.MyDataBase.Take(10).ToList();
```

**View**:

```
<table id="example" class="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover">
   <tbody>
     @foreach (var p in Model)
         {
          <tr class="gridRow" data-id="@p.MyId">
          <td>@p.Id</td>
              // etc....
```

**Script:**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        // Initialize Example
        $('#example').dataTable();
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

I Suggest you go through server side processing of datatables.net . Refer [Datatables.net](https://datatables.net/examples/server_side/simple.html)

Answer (score -2):

Just tweak your method to receive 2 parameters: **pageNumber** **pageResults**

Than adding `Skip` to jump through the results you don't want to show, and using `Take` to start taking results from the point `Skip` skipped over.

**Usage:**

- `Listing(1, 20)` - Will give us results 0-20
- `Listing(3, 20)` - Will give us results 60-80
- `Listing(5, 10)` - Will give us results 50-60

**Code:**

```
public PartialViewResult Listing(int pageNumber, int pageResults)
{
    var model = _db.MyDataBase
        .OrderBy(row => row.ID)
        .Skip((pageNumber -1) * pageResults)
        .Take(pageResults)
        .ToList();
}
```

Comment: whats providing the `int pageNumber` and `int pageResults`?

Comment: You. Pass whoever calling this method with those two parameters. They can arrive from the `POST` a user executed in order to go into Page 2 or from another method that wants Page 3 with 10 results.

Comment: You should provide us with more information, The Client code or Server code that calls `Listing` action from the first place.

Comment: Which column you want the results will be ordered by ? DateCreated ? Author ? And you want them Ascending or Descending order ?

Comment: Well normally jquery datatables would order the incoming data, however just order by ID ascending for testing purposes.